# XLT open File Right click - > Open

Tags: excel, vb.net

If i need to edit .xlt file from certain path i use the command

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\FileName.xlt"

If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
    Process.Start(FILE_NAME)
End If
```

After making changes on it when i want to `CTRL + S` ( Save file ) it just popup me new window where and how to change. That makes me a lot of troubles.

If i go manually on that path  `"C:\FileName.xlt"` Right click on File and Choose Open . After making changes i just `CTRL + S` ( Save ) and it saves changes without any further prompts.

Comment: this problem doesn't have anything to do with the code. check https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/ctrl-s-bizzare-behaviour/da127c1f-a169-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?auth=1

Comment: @Subaz I understand it but you can bypass that if you do RIght click on File and then Open :) Is it possible do with code

Comment: a blind guess: provide admin authorization?

Comment: Can you show us the UDF that interacts with the file and how you close the file?

Comment: There is no interaction with file at all. File is located on some network path. So i made simple exe which show all files from that path and allow end user to modify it.